# Superpositioning of fire

Tags: everyday-life, estimation, superposition, home-experiment

I once recognized that when you light two candles and you move one of the candles towards the other, you will see that the total fire height (let's call it $f_3$) is higher than the sum of the single fires.

Candle 1: fire height $f_1$

Candle 2: fire height $f_2$

Candle 1+2 (the two fires touches each other): height $f_3>f_1+f_2$

I think this has something to do with the superpositioning principle in physics but I am not able to fully explain it with that, do you have any ideas?

Comment: How are sure that height of $f_3$ is greater? Did you use scale to measure the height? Why I am asking is, I have performed your experiment now, and it is pretty difficult to measure the heights.

Comment: I did not use any accurate measurement methods for the height. I held the candles in front a white board and tried to measure the heights with a simple pencil. But it was obvious for me to see that the final height was definitely higher than the sum of the single heights. I used normal matches, normal lighters and normal wax candles.

Comment: Superposition only works for linear systems and a burning candle is, for sure, not a linear system. Indeed, the more candles you bundle, the higher the temperature will be, the faster wax will evaporate and that will make the fire burn faster. Take a thousand candles and you would have a rather unpleasant fire hazard that even the fire department would have a hard time fighting.

Comment: Using the increasing heat as main argument makes sense. The evaporating wax might have an influence for the candle but not for the matches nor a normal lighter. So in the end it is just the increase in heat when combining two or more flames? It would be ineteresting to see what proportions we would hav there

Comment: Search for the pdf version of Faraday's lectures on candle, The Chemical History of Candle. You might enjoy it.

Comment: Second the Faraday recommendation.  BTW, what we see as the "flame" is actually the region where particles cool down by emitting photons.  The oxidation (combustion) occurs underneath that location and typically the gases are invisible there.

Answer (score 3):

When placing the candles next to each other you effectively create a single "fire". We know, from work by [Thomas et al (1961)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0010-2180(61)90117-1) that the flame length is:
$$l/D=f\left(\frac{\dot m^2}{\rho^2gD^5\beta\Delta T}\right)$$
Where $l$ is flame length, $D$ is diameter of fuel, $\dot m$ is fuel mass lose/flow rate, $\rho$ is fuel density, $g$ is acceleration due to gravity, $\beta$ is expansion coefficient of air and $\Delta T$ is average excess temperature of flame.

Therefore if you increase the mass loss rate the flame length will increase. In your case you will be increasing the fuel mass loss rate as you're increasing the burning area and increasing the heat feedback to the fuel surface and hence the vapourisation of the wax.

Simple empirical relationships have been developed for pool fires for a range of fuels. For example by McCaffrey (1995)$^1$:

$$l/D=0.23Q_c^{2/5}-1.02D$$

Where $Q_c$ is the convective heat release rate.

1: McCaffrey, B., Beyler, C.L. and Heskestad, G., 1995. SFPE handbook of fire protection engineering. Flame Height.” National Fire Protection Association: Quincy, MA.

Comment: Dear cyuut, is it possible to provide the direct links to the articles? I've been able to find this: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.369.5324&rep=rep1&type=pdf . Thank you

Comment: Hi pppqqq. I've added the Thomas et al link but McCaffrey is in a non-online publication. I've added the reference.